# regex (digit+whitespace+letter)

Tags: regex, xsd

I write xsd file and need regex to verify my string.I verify effective range of guns. It must be like 100 m. I'm new to regex and wrote like `^\d*\w*[m]?` but it doesn't work.I hope for your help!

Thanks, Vika!

Comment: Guns vs. regex?! :) As for regex, note it may match an empty space at the beginning of a string as all subpatterns are optional. Try `^\d+\s*m$`

Comment: Does it mean my regex suits you best? Is `m` optional or obligatory? I do not understand the question fully, what is optional and what is obligatory, that is why it is hard to post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want `^\d+\s*m?$`

Here's what it means:

- `^` : start of string
- `\d+` : some digits
- `\s*` : some spaces (maybe none)
- `m?` : the "m" letter, optional (`[m]?` was doing the same but a class is useless when you only want one letter)
- `$` : the end of string

It's easy to adapt if your requirements are slightly different, for example when you don't want the space or the m letter to be optional. I encourage you to check you really understand this regex before using it.

Note that string boundaries are normally useless in XSD schema patterns, so if I understand your question you can use `\d+\s*m?`.

Comment: I has this code in xsd  `<xs:element name="effectiveRange">
                     <xs:simpleType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                       <xs:pattern value='^\d+\s*m?'/>
                      </xs:restriction>
                     </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>` 
and in xml have `<effectiveRange>500 m</effectiveRange>`
when I validate xml with xsd I 've error
Value '500 m' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '^\d+\s*m' for type '#AnonType_effectiveRangeTTCWeaponGun'.

Comment: Change it to `<xs:element name="effectiveRange"> <xs:simpleType> <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> <xs:pattern value='\d+\s*m?'/> </xs:restriction> </xs:simpleType> </xs:element>`

Comment: Thank you! It works, but why I must delete '^' in regex?

Comment: @vika because it's a string boundary, and they're implicit in XSD pattern: the pattern always apply to the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

`\w` in regex means *any word character (letter, number, underscore)* so `\w` does not do what you think it does.

Your regex would look like this:

```
`^\d+\s*m?`
```

Explained:

- `^` - start of string / line (depending on any flags like `m` for multiline)
- `\d+` - shorthand for matching `[0-9]` e.g. any digit. `+` making it a one-or-more match.
- `\s*` - match a whitespace character including tabs etc... `*` making it zero or more times
- `m?` - match a literal `m` character and make it optional with `?`

My references and tools I use to build regexes and have a cheatsheet:

- http://regexr.com
- http://rubular.com

Two very good tools that can help you create more robust regexes easily as well as provide proper explanation as to what something does.

Answer (score 0):

In XSD you can add XSD pattern for space like this:

```
xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]" />
```